# Не работает скрипт jQuery (на проверку ширины экрана), нужна помощь

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, media-queries

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при ширине экрана меньше 992px действие не срабатывало, я прописал код с проверкой ширины экрана, но все ровно скрип работает если уменьшать экран. Если перегрузить страницу на ширине 991px, код работает как надо (функция по клику не срабатывает на экране меньше чем 992px), но при увеличении ширины функция также не работает, хотя должна. Может кто поможет, так как я только начал разбираться в jquery.

Вот ссылка на проект: https://plupiks.github.io/Webovio-Full-Landing/

```
function addQuote() {
  if ($('window').width() >= 992) {
    $('.features-block__image').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var xClick = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
      var yClick = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
      $(this).next('.fetures-block__quote').css({
        "top": yClick,
        "left": xClick
      }).toggleClass('quote-active');
    })
  }
}

$(window).on('load resize', addQuote());
```

Comment: проблема в том, что если изначально ширина больше 991, то к блоку привязывается обработчик. И пока вы его вручную не уберёте, он так и будет выполнятся. Лучше перенесите проверку ширина в обработчик click.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Перенёс проверку ширины в обработчик click и теперь все работает)

```
function addQuote() {
 $('.features-block__image').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
      var xClick = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
      var yClick = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
      $(this).next('.fetures-block__quote').css({
        "top": yClick,
        "left": xClick
      }).toggleClass('quote-active');
    } else {
      $('.features-block__image').click(function(){
        return false;
      })
    }
  })
}

$(window).on('load resize', addQuote())
```